# AppleScript duplicate folder inside pre-existing folder

Tags: macos, applescript

I'm wondering if there is a way using ApplesScript to duplicate a folder, and all the files/folders inside to another location - while leaving any files that exist inside the location intact?

Comment: sure, have a look at some of these: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bapplescript%5D+duplicate+folder

Comment: Hi adamh. I'm well aware that it is possible to duplicate folders with applescript. What I'm not aware of, and what this question is about, is how to do so while keeping existing files/folders intact.

Comment: Duplicate will keep the source intact, moving is another mater.

Comment: Do you mean, duplicate the current state of the folder, so no changes can be made to it while being duplicated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
tell application "Finder" to duplicate folder "Macintosh HD:Users:YourCompName:Desktop:Test1" to "Macintosh HD:Users:YourCompName:Desktop:Test2"
```

Comment: @Leeor Hi, just curious as to what the edits were for on my script?

Comment: only formatting, you can click the "[edited .. ago](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/26293631/revisions)" to see the changes.

Comment: @Leeor Ya I see that, just thought it was good as is, because now it looks like only the file paths are code and the rest isn't...

Comment: My apologies, I hadn't noticed it was meant as code. I did a rollback, but please try to avoid code-only answers

Comment: I ended up using shell script instead, but this answer works too

Comment: @Ke. To each their own :) Shell script is probably faster. Depends on how many you are moving and the content size.